# No read or write method found for field (EMPTY) in class

Tags: java, objectmapper, dozer

I am using a Pojo genrator to generate Java classes from a yaml file and those classes are used as the object classes. But when I run the script it keeps getting this exception.

java.lang.AssertionError: (E2E_Scenarios - Baseline USA) No read or write method found for field (EMPTY) in class (class com.primerica.testautomation.api.common.structure.newmodel.MilitaryPayGrades)
Caught by > Failure processing dataset row: partialProspect, partialProspect, PartialProspect, E2E_Scenarios:testcase-1:PartialProspect:0
at com.github.dozermapper.core.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.determinePropertyType(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:320) ~[dozer-core-6.5.2.jar:6.5.2]
at com.github.dozermapper.core.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:78) ~[dozer-core-6.5.2.jar:6.5.2]
at com.github.dozermapper.core.fieldmap.FieldMap.getDestFieldType(FieldMap.java:120) ~[dozer-core-6.5.2.jar:6.5.2]
at com.github.dozermapper.core.util.MappingUtils.applyGlobalCopyByReference(MappingUtils.java:211) ~[dozer-core-6.5.2.jar:6.5.2]
at com.github.dozermapper.core.loader.MappingsParser.processMappings(MappingsParser.java:169) ~[dozer-core-6.5.2.jar:6.5.2]
at com.github.dozermapper.core.loader.CustomMappingsLoader.load(CustomMappingsLoader.java:61) ~[dozer-core-6.5.2.jar:6.5.2]
at com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder.loadCustomMappings(DozerBeanMapperBuilder.java:741) ~[dozer-core-6.5.2.jar:6.5.2]
at com.github.dozermapper.core.DozerBeanMapperBuilder.build(DozerBeanMapperBuilder.java:588) ~[dozer-core-6.5.2.jar:6.5.2]
at com.primerica.testautomation.api.request.DataMapping.buildMapper(DataMapping.java:179) ~[qa-az-api-core-2.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at com.primerica.testautomation.api.request.DataMapping.map(DataMapping.java:828) ~[qa-az-api-core-2.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at com.primerica.testautomation.api.request.DataMapping.map(DataMapping.java:846) ~[qa-az-api-core-2.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at com.primerica.testautomation.api.datasets.Dataset.applyDatasetRow(Dataset.java:615) ~[qa-az-api-core-2.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at com.primerica.testautomation.api.datasets.SelfServeModernizationDataset.applyDatasetRow(SelfServeModernizationDataset.java:1053) ~[classes/:?]
at com.primerica.testautomation.api.datasets.Dataset.applyDatasetSection(Dataset.java:728) ~[qa-az-api-core-2.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at com.primerica.testautomation.api.steps.ProjectStepBase.applySection(ProjectStepBase.java:103) ~[classes/:?]
at com.primerica.testautomation.api.steps.ProjectSteps.processGivenSection(ProjectSteps.java:194) ~[classes/:?]
at ✽.I fill out the Partial Prospect section(workspace/iba/selfserve/qa-prem-bff-api-iba/target/classes/features/mainframe/PA_IBA_BASE.feature:9) ~[?:?]
[INFO] (CoreHooks:215) - Failed Dataset Cases List > SelfServeModernizationDataset:E2E_Scenarios:1

I have updated the MapperFeature from OjectMapper to JSonMapper but nothing seems to be working.